# how to save class variable value after testcase execution?

Tags: python, pytest

I need to save  `unit_of_measure_id` in class variable to use it in other test case, but its still none even after I assign value to it in `test_create_unit_of_measure` test case . any ideas how to fix this?

```
class Test_EndToEnd(ApiUrls):
    random_num = random.randint(1, 50)
    token = None
    unit_of_measure_id = None
    warehouse_id = None
    country_id = None
    city_id = None
    category_id = None
    manufacturer_id = None
    supplier_id = None
    product_id = None

    @pytest.fixture
    def login(self):
        body = {
            "userName": "someemail@email.com",
            "password": "password"
        }
        login_request = requests.post(url=self.login_url, json=body)
        if login_request.status_code == 200:
            login_json = json.loads(login_request.content)
            get_token = login_json.get("accessToken")
            header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + get_token}

        return header

    def test_create_unit_of_measure(self, login):
        body = {
            "description": "testUnit",
            "name": "unit{}".format(self.random_num)
        }
        create_unit = requests.post(url=self.unit_of_measure_create_url, json=body, headers=login)
        if create_unit.status_code == 201:

            create_unit_json = json.loads(create_unit.content)
            self.unit_of_measure_id = create_unit_json.get("id")
            assert create_unit.status_code == 201
        else:
            assert False
```

Comment: Are you sure that create_unit_json has an id field set? Also, it's not a very good practice to keep state between tests. There is no nice way to guarantee that the tests will be run in the order you expect and a failure in a test will cascade to the others making it hard to debug. Tests should be independent of each other in general.

Comment: yes it has id for sure. i know that independence between test cases is important, but if i do not save the id, i have to merge  2 cases to have that id in other one, without that id other test will not pass. what would be your solution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are initializing that variable, you want to use `Test_EndToEnd.unit_of_measure_id` instead of `self`, which makes it effectively static.  Running some vanilla pytests locally, a new class instance is created for each of the tests, so `self` variables would not be preserved.

As the comment to your question stated, though, this is bad practice and tests should be independent. If you need a value that is calculated, to preserve independence you should move that calculation into the test (possibly into a helper function to avoid code repetition) or add it to your fixture.